# How could I remove just one dictionary which I know the value?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to remove the row which value = 0  in swift
I want to remove the Firebase data from client.
But don't know how to remove just one dictionary (just like the attachment)
Help!!!

Version:

Xcode 9.1,Swift 4.0

Comment: "But don't know how to remove just one dictionary"  Nobody does.

Answer (score 0):

What ever the response your getting you can manipulate from your side by converting into `Dictionary` and manipulates like:

```
var dict = ["key1": 0, "key2": 2]
for (key, value) in dict {
    if value == 0 {
        dict.removeValue(forKey: k)
    }
}

print(dict)
```

**OR**

```
var dict = ["key1": 0, "key2": 2]
dict = dict.filter { $0.value != 0 }
print(dict)
```

output for both :

> ["key2": 2]